# Cannot delete rows in GridView(PosgtesQL) by _RowDeleting command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have asp.net web application, and i need to delete rows in my GridView1 which works with PostgreSQL. I need to delete rows, but i don't have to use ObjectDataSource. Here's my GridView1_RowDeleting method:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int ID2 = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);


        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["postgresConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM mainpage WHERE id=@ID";
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID2", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ID2;
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

And here's my GridView in .aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1650px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" >
```

Each time i'm clicking delete button i get error: "Index is out of range. The index must be a positive number, and its size should not exceed the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index".
   I think problem in my int Id.
   What i've tryed:

```
int ID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
string ID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); and much more...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` occurred because you're not setting `DataKeyNames` attribute property on the grid, hence the row index is still out of bounds when calling `e.RowIndex`. You should set it to ID/primary key column name like this:

```
DataKeyNames="[ID or PK column name]"
```

Here is an example usage:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
              Width="1650px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Update 1**

Additionally, I found parameter name mismatch on this query:

```
string query = "DELETE FROM mainpage WHERE id=@ID";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID2", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ID2;
```

The correct one should be like example below:

```
string query = "DELETE FROM mainpage WHERE id=@ID";
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = ID2;
```

Reference: [GridView.DataKeyNames Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_GridView_DataKeyNames)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tryed to add DataKeyNames="id" in <asp:GridView>, now error says: "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property named id."

Comment: Change to actual primary key field name inside the table you want to delete its record, the code above is just an example. Also I found that you've parameter name mismatch for `DELETE` query (included in edit).

Comment: Awesome! It's work right now. But in my project i have one aspx page with three buttons, each button shows another gridviews from different databases. Now i have to figure out how to delete data from another databases

Comment: The concept sounds somewhat similar, just provide ID to delete from `DataKeyNames` set for each grid. If you feel that current problem is already done, you can [mark this problem as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and open another issue separately.